# Why do my tests pass when run together, but fail individually?

Tags: java, junit4

Not to be confused with a previously asked question "Why do my tests fail when run together, but pass individually?"

I have a task where I need to modify Junit test classes to handle multiple database testing. Before I can implement that, I need to make sure all tests are running without failures. A thing that mystifies me is that now when I run all classes together it shows it ran with no failures. When I ran one class in specific it suddenly had a failure, result persists if I repeat it.

What might be causing this?

I did not write the tests myself, therefore my knowledge of what is in them is limited. I did modify like 3 of them though.

Pasting the failing test in case it helps

```
@Test
public void testGetBetonFillerPrM3Str() {
    Composition c = new Composition();
    MixoSettings settings = new MixoSettings();
    settings.setWcwpDecNum(2);

    assertThat(c.getBetonFillerPrM3Str(), is(""));

    c.setSettings(settings);
    c.setBetonFillerKg(200d);
    c.setTotalVolume(200d);
    assertThat(c.getBetonFillerPrM3Str(), is("1"));

    setUSLocale();
    assertThat(c.getBetonFillerPrM3Str(), is("2"));
    setDKLocale();

    c.setBetonFillerKg(200d);
    c.setTotalVolume(0d);
    assertThat(c.getBetonFillerPrM3Str(), is(""));

    c = new Composition();
    assertThat(c.getBetonFillerPrM3Str(), is(""));
}
```

I am using Eclipse, java 7, JUnit 4

Comment: `setUSLocale` makes me think you change the default locale, which is a great source of problems with tests, as it modifies global state that other tests might rely on. You probably have some tests that assume something about the default locale (or some other global state) that's not always true. The first step is to undo any such modification in a @TearDown method (not in the test, as that might not run if the test fails) and ideally each test should set up that global state if it depends on it.

Comment: If tests only work when run together that indicates they are operating on some shared state which could be something in the JVM as Joachim suggested or even some data in a database. So you'd need to find out why they failed, i.e. what state was expected, what you got instead and why you got that. With that data you then can make an informed decision of whether the tests need to be fixed or your code is already broken.

Comment: the guess Joachim made was correct and solved my problem. Both of your comments were good but I cant mark either of the as the answer because they are comments not answers :(

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue where a few test would fail when run together vs running them individually. I realized it was because I had asynchronous code. I had a completable future with an executorService. In an @AfterEach method I added Thread.sleep(1000) and this solve my issue. Your issue may not be a multi-thread issue, but ultimately you might have to reset any shared values in your @BeforeEach or @AfterEach.

I would also try commenting out test until you find out which test that is run before hand, causes your test at hand to fail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30259685)